# Are there any natural non-antisymmetric binary operations that satisfy the Jacobi identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, examples-counterexamples, binary-operations

A binary operation $\times$ on a commutative monoid is defined to satisfy the [Jacobi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity) if, for all $a$, $b$, and $c$ in the monoid,
$$ a \times (b \times c) + c \times (a \times b) + b \times (c \times a) = 0.$$

The Wikipedia article gives several examples of common binary operations that obey the Jacobi identity: the cross product of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the Lie bracket, the Poisson bracket in classical mechanics, and the operator commutator and Moyal bracket in quantum mechanics.  For all of these examples, the binary operation is antisymmetric (or at least alternating, technically).  Are there any natural examples of binary operations that satisfy the Jacobi identity but aren't antisymmetric(/alternating)?  By "natural," I mean "not cooked up specifically to be an example of a non-antisymmetric operator that satisfies the Jacobi identity" :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the skew-symmetric context, the bracket $[x,[y,z]]$ can freely be rewritten as $-[x,[z,y]]$, $-[[y,z],x]$, $[[z,y],x]$... which gives many ways of writing the Jacobi identity. If skew-symmetry is dropped, this yields many non-equivalent ways to rewrite (or rather, to lift) the Jacobi identity. One way of lifting is of importance:

$$[[x,y],z]=[[x,z],y]+[x,[y,z]]$$

It means that right multiplications are derivations. A (non-associative) algebra satisfying this axiom is called (right) [Leibniz algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_algebra).

Comment: Interesting.  Strictly speaking, this identity you write is unrelated to the Jacobi identity (for a general, not necessarily antisymmeric bilinear operator), and so your answer is unrelated to my question.  But are you implying that the Jacobi identity is "in the wrong form," in the sense that it is not useful/interesting for a non-antisymmetric bilinear operator, whereas the identity that you wrote is "better," in the sense that it is equivalent to the Jacobi identity for an antisymmetric bilinear operator, but also interesting/useful even for a non-antisymmetric bilinear operator?

Comment: Unrelated? It depends what you call the Jacobi identity. If we consider that originally this is a formula written in an algebra with skew-symmetric product, then the formula has many ways to be lifted to an arbitrary product and the above Leibniz formula is one of them. Of course, if you call Jacobi formula only the lift you have chosen, then it's indeed another formula. You have the same issue if you define, say, the "binomial expansion formula" in a non-commutative setting.

Comment: "If we consider that originally this is a formula written in an algebra with skew-symmetric product..." I see now: you were assuming that the Jacobi identity "originally" only applied to antisymmetric products, while I was going off the Wikipedia definition, which makes no mention of antisymmetry.  But it sounds like you agree that the particular lift to an arbitrary product that I wrote in my OP is not particularly interesting/useful?

Comment: I think that Loday introduced Leibniz algebras because this choice of lift, rather than the more naive 1-sided one, has better properties (notably a well-behaved cohomology theory). I guess that before Loday introduced Leibniz algebras, no lift at all of the Jacobi identity was expected to be of particular interest.

Answer (score 0):

Jean-Louis Loday introduced *Leibniz algebras* (which are Lie algebras, without skew-symmetry, see Yves' answer), because it appears "naturally" in algebraic K-theory. Roughly speaking the Lie algebra homology is related to the appearance of cyclic homology.

Reference: Jean-Louis Loday, Daniel Quillen, Cyclic homology and the Lie algebra homology of matrices, Comm. Math. Helv. 59, n. 1, 565-591 (1984).

Lie algebra homology involves the Chevalley-Eilenberg chain complex, which in turns involves the exterior powers of the Lie algebra. Loday found that there is a noncommutative generalization where one has the tensor and not the exterior powers of the Lie algebra in the complex; this new complex defines the Leibniz homology of Lie algebras.